# how would I delete item's in a dictionary within specific parameters?

Tags: dictionary, lambda, key

for my code I want all numbers from a dictionary under 70 to be deleted, I'm unsure of how to specify this and I need it to also delete the associated name with that number as well, either that or only diplay numbers that are 70 or above.
Below is the code that I have in it's entirety:

```
name = []
number =[]
name_grade = {}
counter = 0
counter_bool= True
num_loop = True
while counter_bool:
    stu = int(input("please enter the number of students: "))
    if stu < 2:
        print("value is too low, try again")
        continue
    else:
        break

while counter != stu:

    name_inp = str(input("Enter your name: "))
    while num_loop:
        number_inp = int(input("Enter your number: "))
        if number_inp < 0 or number_inp > 100:
            print("The value is too high or too low, please enter a number between 0 and 100.")
            continue
        else:
            break
    
    name_grade[name_inp] = number_inp
    name.append(name_inp)
    number.append(number_inp)

    counter += 1

print(name_grade)
sorted_numbers = sorted(name_grade.items(), key= lambda x:x[1])
print(sorted_numbers)
if number > 70:
    resorted_numbers = number < 70
print(resorted numbers)
```

how would I go about this?

Also if it's also not too much trouble could someone explain in detail about dictionary keys and how the lambda function I've used works? I got help but I would prefer to know the small details on how it's applied and formatted but don't worry if it's a pain to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just iterate over the dictionary and filter for values less than 70:

```
resorted_numbers = {k:v for k,v in name_grade.items() if v<70}
```

`dict.items` method returns a list of key-value tuple pairs of a dictionary, so the lambda function is telling the `sorted` function to sort by the second element in each tuple.

Comment: Im assuming using with using K:V that's a generally placeholder for the later argument?

Comment: It’s creating a new dictionary from name_grade.